# EntityFrameworkCore SQLite in-memory db tables are not created

Tags: c#, sqlite, integration-testing, in-memory-database, entity-framework-core-2.2

For integration tests I am using an `EntityFrameworkCore` `SQLite` in-memory db and creating its schema as per Microsoft docs, but when I attempt to seed data an exception is thrown that tables do not exist.

The mouse-over docs for `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` :

> Ensure that the database for the context exists.  If it exists, no
>   action is taken.  If it does not exist then the database and all its
>   schema are created.  If the database exists, then no action is made to
>   ensure it is compatible with the model for this context.

I've read that an `EntityFrameworkCore` in-memory db only exists as long as an open connection exists, and so I tried explicitly creating a `var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");` instance and wrapping the below code in a `using(connection) {}` block and passing the connection instance `options.UseSqlite(connection);`, but `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` still doesn't create any db-objects

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder()
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
      using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=MySharedInMemoryDb;mode=memory;cache=shared"))
      {
          connection.Open();
          builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
          {
              var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
                  .AddEntityFrameworkSqlite()
                  .BuildServiceProvider();

              services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
              {
                  options.UseSqlite(connection);
                  options.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
              });

              var contextServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

              // we need a scope to obtain a reference to the database contexts
              using (var scope = contextServiceProvider.CreateScope())
              {
                  var scopedProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;

                  var logger = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebApplicationFactory<TStartup>>>();

                  using (var myDb = scopedProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>())
                  {
                      // DEBUG CODE
                      // this returns script to create db objects as expected
                      // proving that MyDbContext is setup correctly
                      var script = myDb.Database.GenerateCreateScript();
                      // DEBUG CODE

                      // this does not create the db objects ( tables etc )
                      // this is not as expected and contrary to ms docs
                      var result = myDb.Database.EnsureCreated();

                      try
                      {
                          SeedData.PopulateTestData(myDb);
                      }
                      catch (Exception e)
                      {
                          // exception is thrown that tables don't exist
                          logger.LogError(e, $"SeedData.PopulateTestData(myDb) threw exception=[{e.Message}]");
                      }
                  }
              }
          });
        }
        builder.UseContentRoot(".");
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
```

Please note that in this post I'm only asking the question why doesn't `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` create the schema as expected. I'm not presenting the above code as a general pattern for running integration-tests.

Comment: What is `chatDb`? Should it be `MyDb`?

Comment: oops fixed now.

Comment: EF Core in-memory databases (as opposed to SQLite in-memory) don’t have the behavior you describe. Can you point me to the document where you found this so I can fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 49):

## Using a non-shared SQLite in-memory database

SQLite in-memory databases are by default transient. As the [documentation states](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html):

> The database ceases to exist as soon as the database connection is closed. Every :memory: database is distinct from every other.

EF Core's `DbContext` on the other hand, always opens and closes connections to the database automatically, unless you pass an already open connection.

Therefore, in order to use the same SQLite in-memory database across multiple calls in EF Core, you need to create a `SqliteConnection` object separately and then pass it to every `DbContext`.

For example:

```cs
  var keepAliveConnection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");
  keepAliveConnection.Open();

  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
  {
    options.UseSqlite(keepAliveConnection);
  });
```

Note that `SqliteConnection` isn't really thread-safe, so this approach is applicable only to single-threaded scenarios. Any time you want to have a shared database that can be accessed by multiple threads (e.g. in an ASP.NET Core application, servicing multiple requests), you should consider using an on-disk database.

By the way, this is the approach currently used in the [EF Core documentation on how to use SQLite in-memory databases for testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite#writing-tests).

## Using a shared SQLite in-memory database

SQLite also supports named [shared in-memory databases](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html#sharedmemdb). By using the same connection string, multiple `SqliteConnection` objects can connect to the same database. However:

> The database is automatically deleted and memory is reclaimed when the last connection to the database closes.

So it is still necessary to maintain a separate open connection object for the database to be usable across multiple EF Core calls. For example:

```cs
  var connectionString = "DataSource=myshareddb;mode=memory;cache=shared";
  var keepAliveConnection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
  keepAliveConnection.Open();

  services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
  {
    options.UseSqlite(connectionString);
  });
```

Note that this approach isn’t limited to a single thread, because each `DbContext` gets its own instance of `SqliteConnection`.

Comment: why would `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` involve "(using) the same SQLite in-memory database across multiple calls in EF Core" ?  And in any event (as I noted in my post) I've already tried explicitly creating a `var connection = new SqliteConnection("DataSource=:memory:");` instance and wrapping my code in a `using` block and passing the connection instance `options.UseSqlite(connection);`
, but `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` still doesn't create any db-objects.

Comment: `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated();` is a framework method on `DatabaseFacade` and I'd expect it only makes a single call into the in-memory `SQLite` instance to execute a create script identical to that returned by `DbContext.Database.GenerateCreateScript();
`

Comment: I'm not sure how closely you read my post because as the title states my intent here is only to perform integration-tests and so single-threaded is fine.

Comment: EnsureCreated(), like any other API that performs work on the database, will open a connection and close it. I.e. it will not leave an open connection to the just created database. Given that SQLite in-memory databases work in this very unique way, the database is destroyed immediately after being created. So while the tables are being created, with your current code you don’t have a chance to observe it.

Comment: I did read your question closely. That part of my answer is for everyone else that ever finds this answer because they are trying to do similar things (but not exactly the same) as you. Using SQLite in-memory databases has this specific pitfall that it is worth calling out.

Comment: Are you saying that `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` does not and can not serve any useful purpose for a `SQLite` in-memory database because `EnsureCreated()` utilizes its own connection which it immediately closes and that deletes all schema just created ?  So that schema is transient and inaccessible to any consumers ?  But I thought the primary purpose of `EnsureCreated()` is to enable test-db spin-up/down in the context of integration-tests ?  How else to easily create entity-based schema within an in-memory db for the purpose of integration-tests ?

Comment: Yes, because SQLite's behavior with in-memory database is quite different from any other ADO.NET provider, and EF Core doesn't special case it. I am also giving you the solution on how to make it work (passing an open connection).

Comment: How is that a solution ? The purpose of an in-memory database is for prototyping and ease of coding and speed of running automated-tests. Without ability to easily create schema from an entity object-model I'm not understanding the value proposition of an in-memory db. Perhaps `DbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()` was intended to work exactly as one would expect ( and as is documented in MS docs ) but perhaps some cross-platform concern got in the way and nobody bothered to update the docs or blog about the reasons. Unfortunately this pattern has been all to common as .NET Core evolves.

Comment: A better solution is actually provided by SQLite itself in [sharable in-memory databases](https://www.bricelam.net/2015/12/10/shareable-in-memory-databases.html), which Microsoft.Data.Sqlite also supports. These allow several connection object to access the same named in-memory database instance. I will update my answer to take advantage of these.

Comment: Ok I tried this : `using` a new shared-memory mode connection, open the connection, establish db-context using the connection, call `EnsureCreated`, attempt to seed data. But the db-objects are still not present on attempt to access them.

Comment: We must be doing something different. I have created a simplified console app based on the code you provided at https://gist.github.com/divega/2419f6496066ae4ca82fce63c219abd9.

Comment: Your gist is totally artificial. My code is within the context of a  `CustomWebApplicationFactory` that is necessary to simulate the web app for integration testing.

Comment: Note that `Mode=Memory` is not working on 2.1 but fixed in 3.1. I got it working with this connection string `"DataSource=file::memory:?cache=shared"`